# windows 10 english (united states) keyboard layout in popup but not in settings

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I have configured two languages: English (UK) and Ukrainian.

[image: Language settings with only 2 languages]

Then at some moment (no idea when) the 3rd language - English (US) - appeared in the popup and so I can switch to it by Ctrl+Shift

[image: Keyboard layout toolbar popup with 3 languages]

despite I haven't added it and in Control Panel / Language Settings I still have only 2 languages. If I add English (US) manually in Language Setting and then remove it, English (US) disappears from popup for some time, then appears again.

Looks like a Windows bug or some app is messing with Windows language settings.

Same problem on my work PC except I have only one language - English (UK) - there. So I keep switching to English (US) accidentally which is very annoying.

I'm sure I didn't have this problem on Windows 8.

Comment: Did you recently update to Version 1607 by chance?  Have you looked at the numerous other questions that describe similar problems by people that ran Windows 8.x and Windows 10?

Comment: @Ramhound: I have auto-update enabled. The only similar question I've seen is [this](http://superuser.com/questions/833310/input-method-cant-get-rid-of-eng-united-states?rq=1) but it's not my case as English (US) never disappears except I remove it by adding/removing manually.

Comment: So check your update history; did you recently go from Version 1511 to 1607?

Comment: @Ramhound: the first time the problem appeared was some time ago, maybe months ago. Windows v.1607 is also quite old, so it's difficult to say if it's related with v.1607. Are you trying to say this is Windows bug/feature? Any known cure?

Comment: Andy T, if you understand Russian, see [**my similar problem**](https://github.com/BladeMight/Mahou/issues/43). Use [**Mahou**](https://github.com/BladeMight/Mahou), in it program this problem fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Andy T, have you helped my message? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this problem as well, a few years back.
The most common culprit to this behavior seems to be tracked back to different source based games.
As far as I know, there hasn't been any official fix to this problem.

You can try this solution that i found, in which the registry keys for the US keyboard are simply deleted:

```
Delete branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000409
Delete correspondig registry key (00000409) from branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes
Same in branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002
```

Remember to backup the registry, as I have not tested this myself, and cannot vouch for its validity.

Comment: Here is a batch file that you can add to task scheduler to automate it:
REM should the # change for the localization of the KB I put in this variable
set KeyLocalNum=00000409
reg delete HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\%KeyLocalNum% /f
reg delete HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes /v %KeyLocalNum% /f
reg delete HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Keyboard Layouts\%KeyLocalNum% /f
reg delete HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes /v %KeyLocalNum% /f